# Extract 2 words in any order

Tags: r, regex

I would like to extract cat and dog in any order

```
string1 <- "aasdfadsf cat asdfadsf dog"
string2 <- "asfdadsfads dog asdfasdfadsf cat"
```

What I have now extracts cat and dog, but also the text in-between

```
stringr::str_extract(string1, "cat.*dog|dog.*cat"
```

I would like the output to be

```
cat dog
```

and

```
dog cat
```

for string1 and string2, respectively

Comment: Are you sure it should be `dog cat` for both? I can get `cat dog` for string1 and `dog cat` for string2. Or do you want to get `dog` for string1 and `cat` for string2?

Comment: Hi Wiktor, yes, that's what I meant.  Thanks for the clarification.  Will edit OP accordingly

Comment: Please see my update. I have changed the function from `str_extract` to `str_extract_all` to capture all the groups.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `sub` with the following PCRE regex:

```
.*(?|(dog).*(cat)|(cat).*(dog)).*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fnkDLg/1/).

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars (to match all chars add `(?s)` at the pattern start)
- `(?|(dog).*(cat)|(cat).*(dog))` - a branch reset group `(?|...|...)` matching either of the two alternatives:

  - `(dog).*(cat)` - Group 1 capturing `dog`, then any 0+ chars as many as possible, and Group 2 capturing `cat`
  - `|` - or
  - `(cat).*(dog)` - Group 1 capturing `cat`, then any 0+ chars as many as possible, and Group 2 capturing `dog` (in a branch reset group, group IDs reset to the value before the group + 1)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars

The `\1 \2` replacement pattern inserts Group 1 and Group 2 values into the resulting string (so that the result is just `dog` or `cat`, a space, and a `cat` or `dog`).

See [an R demo online](https://ideone.com/XqUZdZ), too:

```
x <- c("aasdfadsf cat asdfadsf dog", "asfdadsfads dog asdfasdfadsf cat")
sub(".*(?|(dog).*(cat)|(cat).*(dog)).*", "\\1 \\2", x, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] "cat dog" "dog cat"
```

To return `NA` in case of no match, use a regex to either match the specific pattern, or the whole string, and use it with `gsubfn` to apply custom replacement logic:

```
> gsubfn("^(?:.*((dog).*(giraffe)|(giraffe).*(dog)).*|.*)$", function(x,a,b,y,z,i) ifelse(nchar(x)>0, paste0(a,y," ",b,z), NA), x)
[1] "NA" "NA"
> gsubfn("^(?:.*((dog).*(cat)|(cat).*(dog)).*|.*)$", function(x,a,b,y,z,i) ifelse(nchar(x)>0, paste0(a,y," ",b,z), NA), x)
[1] "cat dog" "dog cat"
```

Here,

- `^` - start of the string [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)
- `(?:.*((dog).*(cat)|(cat).*(dog)).*|.*)` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) that matches either of the two alternatives:
  `.*((dog).*(cat)|(cat).*(dog)).*`:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
  - `((dog).*(cat)|(cat).*(dog))` - a [capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) matching either of the two alternatives:

    - `(dog).*(cat)` - `dog` (Group 2, assigned to `a` variable), any 0+ chars as many as possible, and then `cat` (Group 3, assigned to `b` variable)
    - `|`
    - `(cat).*(dog)` - `dog` (Group 4, assigned to `y` variable), any 0+ chars as many as possible, and then `cat` (Group 5, assigned to `z` variable)
  - `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible

    - `|` - or
    - `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `$` - end of the string [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

The `x` in the anonymous function represents the Group 1 value that is "technical" here, we check if the Group 1 match length is not zero with `nchar`, and if it is not empty we replace with the custom logic, and if the Group 1 is empty, we replace with `NA`.

Comment: Wiktor, thank you very much.  Alas, I found something.  If my search string requirements are now "dog" and "giraffe", a test string of "aasdfadsf cat asdfadsf dog" will return "aasdfadsf cat asdfadsf dog", whereas I want it to return NA    https://regex101.com/r/fnkDLg/1/

Comment: Thank you.  Can you please explain the regex syntax, especially the "(?:".  Also, what is the purpose of the i argument in the function?

Comment: `strapply` might also be useful here.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract_all` from the [stringr](/questions/tagged/stringr) package with capture groups.

```
string1 <- "aasdfadsf cat asdfadsf dog"
string2 <- "asfdadsfads dog asdfasdfadsf cat"
string3 <- "asfdadsfads asfdadsfadf"

library(stringr)
str_extract_all(c(string1, string2, string3), pattern = "(dog)|(cat)")
# [[1]]
# [1] "cat" "dog"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "dog" "cat"
# 
# [[3]]
# character(0)
```

We can also set `simplify = TRUE`. The output would be a matrix.

```
str_extract_all(c(string1, string2, string3), pattern = "(dog)|(cat)", simplify = TRUE)
#       [,1]  [,2] 
# [1,] "cat" "dog"
# [2,] "dog" "cat"
# [3,] ""    ""
```

Comment: I wish this worked for what I want because it is so elegant.  However, if BOTH cat and dog aren't present, I want to return NA

Comment: @matsuo_basho Please see my update. When there are no cat and dog, the function returns `character(0)` or `""` depends on `simplify = TRUE`. You may want to replace them with `NA` later.

Comment: I mean that I would like NA returned for the following strings:  "adsfadsf dog asfdadsf", "asdfadsf cat asdfadsf"

Comment: I think what you were trying to say is “Either dog or cat is not present”. Sorry I am not an native English speaker, but I don’t think you provide sufficient information about what was your requirements. Since my output fits your desired output in your post, and you have found the answer you want, I will not modify my post. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Or,

```
> regmatches(string1,gregexpr("cat|dog",string1))
[[1]]
[1] "cat" "dog"

> regmatches(string2,gregexpr("cat|dog",string2))
[[1]]
[1] "dog" "cat"
```